# Show that the Dirichlet problem has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need some help regarding this assignment.

> Let $\Omega = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3: \lvert x \rvert \geq 1 \}$ and consider the Dirichlet problem
>
> $$ \Delta u = 0, \ \ \ x \in \Omega, $$
> $$u = 1, \ \ \ x \in \partial \Omega.  $$
> Show there exist infinitely many solutions to the problem.

I am sure it has to do with working in a three-dimensional space, probably if I an appropriate solution I will be able to vary it in one coordinate and attain infinitely many, but I am struggling.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: In the _plane_ one solution would be $u=1$ and another would be $u=1+\log(|x|)$.

Comment: $1$ and $1/|x|$ are a couple of solutions. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @TrialAndError I have not been able to come to a solution... Did you just guess $\frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert}$ as one solution?

Comment: @Nhat : $1/|x|$ is called the "fundamental solution" of the Laplace equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It's one of those things you should know about. And, of course, you know constant solutions are solutions of the Laplace equation. Both $1$ and $1/|x|$ are identically $1$ on $|x|=1$.